# My Game's Animation is not working properly when i press the "page up" button repeatedly

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Game's Animation is not working properly when i press the "up arrow" button repeatedly  which is mapped to climbing up the ladder. It works properly otherwise when i climb up and then release the up arrow button but if i press the button continously it does not return the idle animation after i stop climbing the ladder.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3MP2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHuFv.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYc9c.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqe4l.png)

I tried to change the animation to idle from climbing ladder . But i am not able to do that

Comment: Please do not paste the code as an image.

Comment: from that mess? who knows.. do some debugging, check your values are what you expect